# I need help to achieve (as close as possible) 40G network transfer speed (~1250 MB/s x 4)

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-esxi, cisco

I had a Gigabit network, which I upgraded recently to 40Gbps.
To do so, I replace my **TPLINK** switch with a **Cisco Nexus 9396PX** switch, which has a module with **12x 40G** ports. The 40G network interconnects **DELL servers with ESXi7** installed.

The problem is that I am not able to achieve the throughput speed of a **40Gbps network (~1250 MB/s x 4)**.

- When I run `iperf` between two virtual machines, I get a bandwidth ranging from **6 Gbits/sec to 10 Gbits/sec**. I never been able to reach the 40 Gbits bandwidth.
- When I copy files with `scp` I am getting a transfer speed of about **110-120 MB/s** which is very far from the theoretical bandwidth **of 1GB/s x 4 ~ 4G/s** for a 40G network.

Recently I discovered that encryption reduce transfer speed so, I set up FTP server. Transfer speed doubled with FTP. I got a transfer rate about **240-280 MB/s**.
I also updated **MTU** to **9000** on both hosts and VMs, but transfer rates are low.

Can anybody, please, help me to identify and solve the issue?
I want 40G Network bandwidth as configured in the Switch to be reflected in Virtual machines, and the transfer speed to reflect as close as possible transfer speed of 40G network (~1250 MB/s x 4).

**This is the current architecture details:**

- Cisco Nexus 9396PX Switch with 40G module
- 4 Dell PowerEdge R930 Servers  (VMware ESXi7 hosts)
- NVME disks on each server
- 40 Gbps Mellanox NIC on  ESXi7 hosts
- QSFP+ DAC cables to connect servers to switch

---

**UPDATES**

I just made 3 more tests. And I can not say there are improvements

**FIRST TEST**

1. In Switch, I checked MTU on the server interface  and noticed it was not set to Maximum. I tried to set it to 9000 but was denied. It can only be set either to **1500** or **9216**. I chosed the highest value.
2. Still in the Switch I fixed speed to **40G/s** and disabled speed auto negociation
3. I disabled speed auto negociation on ESXi hosts from VCenter.

Then I run the tests again. These changes did not affect the `scp` copy speed transfer speed between VMs (Ubuntu 22.04).
But I noticed a light improvement when downloading from FTP server (it is installed on one of the two ubuntu VMs).

**SECOND TEST**

I run the following tests on VMs with Windows 10 installed.

- I added two Windows VM to the host and configured them with **MTU** set to **9000** too.
- I created a shared folder for copy betwnn the two Windows VMs.

When I copy files from **shared folder to local**, the speed is around **600MB/s**. But when I copy from local to shared folder, the copy **starts** at around **350MB/s** and the speed **decreases** when it reaches **~30%**.

**THIRD TEST**

For the last test I installed **Filezilla** on one the the windows VMs and dowloaded files from/to FTP server (on Ubuntu VM).

- Dowload speed is around **450MB/s** when the download starts and at about **~50%** it decreases to **~200MB/s**
- Upload speed is around **200MB/s**

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1127314/38644) was posted yesterday and could be helpful. Especially the second paragraph.

Comment: @yaoviametepe - Yeah, I agree with Gerald, specifically the second paragraph of my answer to that other user - 40Gbps isn't what most people think it is.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider thank you for your answers. This is a valuable information you gave. 
May be I should focus on how to achieve 1G/s of dowload speed with the one line of 10G. Because I can not even achieve this speed.

Answer (score 2):

40 gig is basically a bonded 4*10 gig connection. To benefit from the aggregated bandwidth you need multiple TCP sessions running at the same time. You’ll never reach combined estimated bandwidth with just one process and a single TCP session. Some good description could be read here:

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/lacp-vs-mpio-on-windows-platform-which-one-is-better-in-terms-of-redundancy-and-speed-in-this-case-2

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me confirm that I am on 10Gbps link, not 40G. 
I do not know if it could be related to the virtual settings or not.

The command `iperf3 -c 192.168.1.80 -P 8 -t 60` output summary is:

`...[ 19]   0.00-60.02  sec  7.15 GBytes  1.02 Gbits/sec                  receiver
[SUM]   0.00-60.00  sec  57.0 GBytes  8.16 Gbits/sec  140             sender
[SUM]   0.00-60.02  sec  56.9 GBytes  8.15 Gbits/sec                  receiver`

Comment: A 40G interface is *not* the same as four bonded 10G interfaces. On the former you can get a single flow up to 40G (with some tuning) and on the latter only up to 10G.

Comment: @Zac67 Can you please tell me what values needs to be tuned to achieve 40 Gbits/s throughput  in my VMs?